# Hide all rows and show selected

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to hide all rows and then show selected ones.
My codes are as below. This is working fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer. In IE, all the rows go hidden and nothing displayed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is the code of the table definition

```
<table id="tableID">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Updated on</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="parent">
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>City 1</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the CSS

```
    #tableID tbody tr {
    display : none;
     }


   #tableID tr.parent {
    display : table-row;
    color: blue;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might possible that your IE version does not support the `display: table-row` property. So instead of that try with `display:block`

```
#tableID tr.parent {
    display : block;
    color: blue;
 }
```